# How to set table names and columns as case sensitive in oracle 11g?

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, case-sensitive, database-migration

I have a .NET 4.0 application that uses Entity Framework 4 that connects to a MS SQL 2008 database. The naming convention used is for example table "Clients", fields : "Id", "Id_Order". Now I need to switch from SQL Server to Oracle Server, so I migrated the MS SQL database to oracle database, but the problem is that all the table names and column names are uppercased, so by generating the edmx for oracle(using ODAC), I will have to change in code from "Clients" to "CLIENTS", "Id" to "ID", "Id_Client" to "ID_CLIENT", and it's a lot to change.
The migration was done using the built-in migration tool from Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.07.

A snippet from the generated script:
CREATE TABLE Clients (

I have read that in order to create case-sensitive identifiers you must use double quotes.
So I think the script should be something like this:
CREATE TABLE "Clients" (

Does anyone know a migration tool that perserves names case or at least a general option that I can switch on in the script ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to change the code?  The whole point of Oracle being case-insensitive is that you can refer to the table as `clients`, `Clients`, `CLIENTS`, or even `clIeNtS`, and it will work.

You only use the double-quotes if you want case-sensitivity for some reason, but unless you have table names that are the same apart from case (*shudder*), you shouldn't need it.

Comment: In my .NET 4.0 application I have a lot of linq code like: using(ExampleDbContext context = new ExampleDbContext()) { context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(); }  So if I create an edmx using oracle database I will have to write using(ExampleDbContext context = new ExampleDbContext()) { context.CLIENTS.FirstOrDefault(); } Most of my queries are done in linq where C# is case-sensitive, not in stored procedures.

Comment: In Oracle SQL, you may refer to the table with any combination of case you care to use.  Including `Clients`.  So why would you need to change the LINQ code to say `CLIENTS` instead?

Comment: When you create the edmx file from MS SQL, you have C# generated code like context.Clients, and when you create from Oracle you have C# generated code like context.CLIENTS, so I will have errors on compile- time in my .NET application

Comment: I don't want to have different C# generated code. I know that Oracle database will understand both Clients and CLIENTS, but I need in the edmx to be "Clients", and not "CLIENTS", and I can't offer him "Clients" because the migration tool uppercased all letters.

Comment: Ah, OK, so the problem is with the generated C# code.  Your snippet was from the generated DDL SQL, which is what confused me.

Comment: exactly ! The database is alright, but I will have to modify in C#. The snippet was generated by the migration tool and it is the database script. Now, maybe in the script if the table was named "Clients" (with quotes) the edmx would hold "Clients" as well.