# Entity Framework sends invalid SQL to Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I built a simple class for Entity Framework to query a table in Oracle. The login works and Oracle seems to find the right table.

But Entity Framework sends invalid SQL to the database?

From the trace file

```
2019-09-23 16:01:08.225742 TID:1   (PUB) (ENT) OracleCommandImpl.CheckForReturningClause() Cmd Text (SQL):  HasReturnClauseSearchKey : SELECT 
"c"."Id" AS "Id", 
"c"."Name" AS "Name"
FROM "AB"."TESTTABLE" "c"
WHERE (ROWNUM <= (1) )
```

The result is this error.

> failed in 17 ms with error: ORA-00904: "c"."Name": Invalid ID

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]

My DbContext:

```
namespace Database2
{
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestTable> TestTable { get; set; }

        public TestContext() : base("FOOTEST")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

My App.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FOOTEST" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=XX;Password=YYYY;Data Source=FOOTEST.WORLD"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

My Table

```
Create Table AB.TESTTABLE
  (
  ID NUMBER(22, 0) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  )
```

My table class

```
namespace Database2
{
    [Table("AB.TESTTABLE")]
    public class TestTable
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add both the `class TestTable` and the Oracle table definition?

Comment: `<expr> AS <alias>` is legal syntax in Oracle as well. Rather, it complains that there is no `Name` column in `TESTTABLE`.

Comment: Double quotes make the SQL column names case sensitive, check this [related, non EF, answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808010/2265446)

Comment: You are Right. I get it running in my database Client if I remove all quotation marks. Are this the original Quotation marks EF is sending?